# Need help creating a method that accepts three integers and returns an integer representing the sum of only the even integer

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner in Java and coding in general. I'm having a lot of trouble on filtering out even numbers and adding them together. I understood how to set up the scanner, and having the user input 3 different int's, but the bottom segment is where I'm completely lost. My notes in "Boolean Zen" section say to use `(n1 % 2 != 0 && n2 % 2 != 0)` as a test, but I can't figure out how to use it. I should repeat that I am very new, and started coding barely even 2 weeks ago. I've written:

```
import java.util.*;

public class U3L8Lab3

 {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter 3 Intergers:");
      int num1 = console.nextInt();
      int num2 = console.nextInt();
      int num3 = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println(sumOfEvens(num1, num2, num3));
   }  

   public static int sumOfEvens(int num1, int num2, int num3)
   {
     
   }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Sorry about that one, did not know that. Thanks for educating me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are tasked at summing the even numbers only. From what I understand, if the user had to input 3 uneven numbers, then the result should be 0 - that is the assumption I will make when providing you my answer.

Firstly, you need to determine which of the numbers are even - this is what the mod (%) functionality is for. If any number mod 2 results in 0, it means it is even. So:

```
public static int sumOfEvens(int num1, int num2, int num3)
   {
     int sum = 0;
     if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
       sum += num1;
     }
     if (num2 % 2 == 0) {
       sum += num2;
     }
     if (num3 % 2 == 0) {
       sum += num3;
     }
     return sum;
   }
```

Not the most elegant solution, but I hope you get the gist of it.